# Opacity not respected for tikz drawing if inside pgfplots' axis

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, macros, renewcommand

I define a `myDraw` command that should draw two lines.

The command has an optional parameter.
If I don't pass this parameter, both drawings should be opaque.
Otherwise, the drawing specified in the parameter should be opaque, and the other should be semi-transparent.

The following code works as expected:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xifthen}

\newcommand{\myDraw}[1][]{%
    \newcommand{\tikzTransparent}{0.1}
    \newcommand{\tikzAlpha}{1}

    \ifthenelse{\isempty{#1} \OR \equal{#1}{firstDrawing}}{\renewcommand{\tikzAlpha}{1}}{\renewcommand{\tikzAlpha}{\tikzTransparent}}
    \begin{scope}[opacity=\tikzAlpha]
        \draw (0, 0) -- (1, 0) node[midway,above] {first};
    \end{scope}
    
    \ifthenelse{\isempty{#1} \OR \equal{#1}{secondDrawing}}{\renewcommand{\tikzAlpha}{1}}{\renewcommand{\tikzAlpha}{\tikzTransparent}}
    \begin{scope}[opacity=\tikzAlpha]
        \draw (0, 1) -- (1, 1) node[midway,above] {second};
    \end{scope}
}

\begin{document}
    Both opaque:
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \myDraw[]{}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}

    First opaque, second transparent:
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \myDraw[firstDrawing]{}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}

    First transparent, second opaque:
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \myDraw[secondDrawing]{}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

However, as soon as the drawings are inside a pgfplots' `axis`, then it gives strange results.
It compiles without errors, but the output is wrong.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usepackage{xifthen}

\newcommand{\myDraw}[1][]{%
    \newcommand{\tikzTransparent}{0.1}
    \newcommand{\tikzAlpha}{1}

    \ifthenelse{\isempty{#1} \OR \equal{#1}{firstDrawing}}{\renewcommand{\tikzAlpha}{1}}{\renewcommand{\tikzAlpha}{\tikzTransparent}}
    \begin{scope}[opacity=\tikzAlpha]
        \draw (axis cs:0, 0) -- (axis cs:1, 0) node[midway,above] {first};
    \end{scope}
    
    \ifthenelse{\isempty{#1} \OR \equal{#1}{secondDrawing}}{\renewcommand{\tikzAlpha}{1}}{\renewcommand{\tikzAlpha}{\tikzTransparent}}
    \begin{scope}[opacity=\tikzAlpha]
        \draw (axis cs:0, 1) -- (axis cs:1, 1) node[midway,above] {second};
    \end{scope}
}

\newcommand{\myDrawPgf}[1][]{%
    \begin{axis}[xmin=-0.5,xmax=1.5,ymin=-0.5,ymax=1.5,clip=false]
        \myDraw[#1]{}
    \end{axis}
}

\begin{document}
    Both opaque:
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \myDrawPgf[]{}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}

    First opaque, second transparent:
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \myDrawPgf[firstDrawing]{}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}

    First transparent, second opaque:
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \myDrawPgf[secondDrawing]{}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

Why isn't the second code working and how can I fix it?

Comment: PGFPlots works differently. It caches the scopes/`\draw`s and executes them at the end when it has figured out everything about the plots. It seems that the whole `\ifthenelse` thing is not cached but executes directly and thus only the last one “survives” and will be applied.

Comment: I try to never put `\draw` commands inside an axis environment, but rather use `\coordinate` to save axis cs: coordinates as names and `\draw` using the named coordinates outside the axis environment.

Answer (score 4):

PGFPlots works differently:
It caches the scopes/`\draw`s and executes them at the end when it has figured out everything about the plots. The whole `\ifthenelse` thing is not cached but executed directly and thus only the last definition of `\tikzAlpha` is active.

One way to circumvent this is to put the `\ifthenelse` lines in [`\pgfplotsextra`](https://tikz.dev/pgfplots/path-operations#pgfp.%3CCS%3Epgfplotsextra):

```
\newcommand{\myDraw}[1][]{%
  \newcommand{\tikzTransparent}{0.1}
  \newcommand{\tikzAlpha}{1}

  \pgfplotsextra{
    \ifthenelse{\isempty{#1} \OR \equal{#1}{firstDrawing}}
      {\renewcommand{\tikzAlpha}{1}}
      {\renewcommand{\tikzAlpha}{\tikzTransparent}}
  }
  \begin{scope}[opacity=\tikzAlpha]
    \draw (axis cs:0, 0) -- (axis cs:1, 0) node[midway,above] {first};
  \end{scope}
  
  \pgfplotsextra{
    \ifthenelse{\isempty{#1} \OR \equal{#1}{secondDrawing}}
      {\renewcommand{\tikzAlpha}{1}}
      {\renewcommand{\tikzAlpha}{\tikzTransparent}}
  }
  \begin{scope}[opacity=\tikzAlpha]
    \draw (axis cs:0, 1) -- (axis cs:1, 1) node[midway,above] {second};
  \end{scope}
}
```

Here the manual itself explains a bit about this postponing process that is done automatically for normal TikZ paths. For the `\ifthenelse` this needs to be enabled manually with `\pgfplotsextra`.

---

Reimplementing this purely with PGFKeys sidesteps this since all the decision will be delayed just as well.

### Code

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
%\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz, pgfplots}
\tikzset{
  my draw opacity/.initial=.1,
  my draw/.is choice,
  my draw/default/.style={
    /tikz/my drawing/first/.code=, /tikz/my drawing/second/.code=},
  my draw/first/.style={%
    /tikz/my drawing/first/.style ={opacity=1},
    /tikz/my drawing/second/.style={opacity=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/my draw opacity}}},
  my draw/second/.style={
    /tikz/my drawing/first/.style ={opacity=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/my draw opacity}},
    /tikz/my drawing/second/.style={opacity=1}},
  my draw=default}
\newcommand{\myDraw}[1][]{%
  \begin{scope}[#1]
    \draw[my drawing/first]  (axis cs:0, 0) -- (axis cs:1, 0) node[midway,above] {first};
    \draw[my drawing/second] (axis cs:0, 1) -- (axis cs:1, 1) node[midway,above] {second};
  \end{scope}}

\newcommand{\myDrawPgf}[1][]{%
  \begin{axis}[xmin=-0.5, xmax=1.5, ymin=-0.5, ymax=1.5, clip=false]
    \myDraw[#1]{}
  \end{axis}}

\begin{document}
Both opaque:
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \myDrawPgf[]{}
\end{tikzpicture}

First opaque, second transparent:
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \myDrawPgf[my draw=first]{}
\end{tikzpicture}

First transparent, second opaque:
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \myDrawPgf[my draw=second]{}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: An alternative is to put the content of `\myDraw` in [`\pgfplotsextra`](https://tikz.dev/pgfplots/path-operations#pgfp.%3CCS%3Epgfplotsextra), here the manual also mentions this postponing.

Comment: That's a great and elegant solution. However, the solution you propose in your comment works just as well, and it involves much fewer code changes. I literally just had to slap a `\pgfplotsextra` around `\myDraw` and it worked! Do you want to add it as an answer, so I can upvote it and accept it?